# My Mac switches to speaker after locking the screen

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, macos

When listening to music, after locking my MacBook Pro (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>PWR</kbd>) and leaving, when I come back after 5 mins, I can hear the sound from the external speakers and nothing from my headphones. I have to unplug and replug to get it back to normal.

Anyone experienced this behaviour before? I'm running Sierra 10.12.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make sure that under *System Preferences -> Sound* that the default device (Headphones) is selected. After setting this, my Mac was remembering that I was using headphones after unlocking the screen.